# To Joomla or not to joomla? Is it worth it when you know how to dream in CSS?

Tags: joomla, dreamweaver

Alright masterminds. Should I consider joomla or just stick with hardcore coded webdevelopment?

Explanation:

I am basically a programmer with a pretty good command of HTML, Flash, Dreamweaver, Javascript ( though not an expert...yet).

I do not intend to design websites for customers, I do regularly design sites for my own projects.

I have seen some really cool web layouts done with joomla, and wordpress and the like. Now I know that these are content management systems and my projects are ( generally, though not always) not content management systems.

**FOR EXAMPLE:
Say I had to design the website for t-mobile, or verizon, or vodafone with their phones and offers and what not, now should I be considering a complete design from scratch or should i pick up a nice looking joomla template and MODIFY it so users can browse for phones, order them , buy on contract ( i actually am working on a smaller version of such a site)**

The point being , is it worth spending time modifying a joomla template to your needs or should you just build the whole site from scratch, because after all, "real coders are hard coders??" :)
Any of you out there shedding some light on it would be great help!

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Out of all honesty, I would be more concerned about the functionality rather than design. If you are looking for something along the lines of a e-commerce site then definitely go for Joomla and use a shop extension such as VirtueMart of JoomShopping. With something like this you would need extreme PHP knowledge, therefore can make life very simple by using Joomla and extensions to go with it. Then you can choose a template of your choice of revamp a basic one.

Word of advice though, please oh please don't use flash ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IT depends on what you need really.

I've been building joomla powered websites for years and I have never modified nor used a ready-made template, but always built them according to the PSD (custom design), and for joomla (unlike wordpress for example) all you need to build custom looking joomla website is HTML / CSS knowledge and hopefully a good framework.